# Android performance issues with large Hashmap

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, libgdx, hashmap

I am writing a simple word game using a Java gaming library called LibGDX.

I have a dictionary of 370k words in txt file that takes up about 4mb.

In my game, i read the words in using the following code

```
wordsScored = new HashMap<>();
    double start = System.currentTimeMillis() % 100000;
    Gdx.app.error("1","start "+ start);

    FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("words.txt");
    String allWordsString = handle.readString();
    String wordsArray[] = allWordsString.split("\\r?\\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
        String word = wordsArray[i];
        wordsScored.put(word, scoreWord(word, getGameCards()));
        if(i % 10000 == 0) {
            Gdx.app.error("1","i="+i+" - "+ System.currentTimeMillis() % 100000);
        }
    }
    wordsArray = null;

    double end = System.currentTimeMillis() % 100000;
    Gdx.app.error("1","end "+ end);
    Gdx.app.error("1","total "+ (end-start));
```

When i run this on desktop (you can build on desktop for dev purposes) it takes about 1.5 secs to populate the Hashmap with key and score of word. On Android it takes about 2.5s.

However, after playing on Android 3-4 times, and making no code changes, it suddenly slows right down taking 30-40s!

I'm convinced i have some sort of memory leak, CV or Android is doing something crazy like keeping the Hashmap around like it does with statics.

I tried to use the new Android studio profiler, but that just virtually crashed my machine, and got stuck in a loop whilst everything else on my machine slowed down including mouse etc.

Does anyone know how i can test for this "leak" ?
If Android has any issue with letting resources, data from one game to the next?
If a Hashmap is a poor data structure for this?

Comment: I am stunned that you're not crashing with an `OutOfMemoryError`. You're certainly making life difficult on the heap and garbage collector. I suggest that you reconsider whether you need this entire thing in memory versus accessing only needed bits (e.g., via SQLite queries). Even if you determine that you have to have the whole thing in memory, read it in once per process (not once per game).

Comment: Sorry, when I said per game, i meant once per loading of the application. Even with closing down of the app, and even swiping it away/closing on the recent apps, when i launch the app again, it seems to still have the previous Hashmap. No outOfMemory on any launch of app. But quick (2s) on the first couple of launches, then 30-40s after that

Comment: Swiping your app out of recent apps *may* terminate the process, but that behavior is often tweaked by device manufacturers. If "it still seems to have the previous Hashmap", that's a good thing, as it means that you do not need to load it again. To test the behavior of your app with a fresh process, terminate the existing process from within the IDE (the red square toolbar buttons).

Comment: But if it still has it, how can i get at that data? I can't expect the same variable name to exist with the values. It'll be null.... Maybe I'm not explaining myself when i say, "exists"

Comment: Then apparently you don't know if you have the data. You are the one claiming that "it still seems to have the previous Hashmap", not me. For a massive in-memory data set that you need to use for the entirety of your process, have it be static, perhaps managed by a repository object.

Comment: You're right i don't know if it does, I'm mainly going by gut feeling, hence why i said it 'seems'. Maybe not the best use of the word, or at least not if i wanted to avoid confusion! I don't know what a repository object is, but I'll look it up, thanks

Comment: With respect to the repository pattern, it is covered lightly in [Google's guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide). You're writing a game, and game development presumably has its own set of design patterns. So, a lot of what's in that app architecture page may not be relevant to you. Basically, a repository is a facade, providing a clean API for the rest of the app to get at data, while the repository implementation hides all the dirty details of disk and/or network I/O.

Comment: I agree that this might not be relevant as this game will be released on iOS too, so the Android specific solution may not be applicable. The code is written in Java and then converted for both platforms

Comment: The repository pattern is not Android-specific. IIRC, Microsoft coined the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question does not have any memory leaks that I can see.  If your application does have a leak, then it is somewhere else in your app's code.  (For example, it might be keeping references to multiple `HashMap` objects created by the code.  You have not shown us the context in which `wordsScored` is declared, or explained its lifetime.)

I will grant you that running the code multiple times will generate a lot of garbage, and the issue might be to do with GC performance.  But I think it is more likely that there is a memory leak *somewhere else* in your code (and not Android ...).

---

I thought there might be a "resource leak" due to this line:

```
    FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("words.txt");
```

However, the GDX library doesn't seem to provide any way to "close" a `FileHandle`, so presumably it is not necessary to do that.

Comment: I'm always wary of just dumping huge amounts of code and exciting people to trawl through them, so i try and keep it concise. What I'm now trying, is creating a skeleton app with just the loading of the dictionary, and saving it in the Hashmap etc. I'll report back of this also allows down or not. Thanks for your help

Comment: So, after just writing a simple app that just does the txt -> into Hashmap code, everything runs smoothly over and over again. So glad I've solved that, but not happy that i now have to find a memory leak somewhere in my app!!